# Use generic passed to useForm in custom controller component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

Using `react-hook-form` I'm trying to make a custom `ControlledTextField` component to work with my component library. Following the typescript usage for `userForm` I can create my form like this

```js
export interface AuthenticationData {
  email: string,
  password: string
}
const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm<AuthenticationData>({
  resolver: yupResolver(LoginSchema),
})
```

Then I create my custom `ControlledTextField` component

```js
import { FormControl, Input } from "native-base"
import { Controller, UseControllerProps } from "react-hook-form"

interface ControlledTextFieldProps extends UseControllerProps {
  label: string
}

const ControlledTextField = ({ control, name, label, ...props }: ControlledTextFieldProps) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={name}
      render={({
        fieldState: { invalid, error },
        field: { onChange, onBlur, value },
      }) => (
        <FormControl mb="5" isInvalid={invalid}>
          <FormControl.Label>{label}</FormControl.Label>
          <Input
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onChange={onChange}
            value={value}
          />
          <FormControl.ErrorMessage>
            {error?.message ?? ""}
          </FormControl.ErrorMessage>
        </FormControl>
      )}
    />
  )
}

export default ControlledTextField
```

When attempting to implement I am getting this error

```
Type 'Control<AuthenticationData, any>' is not assignable to type 'Control<FieldValues, any>'.
  The types of '_options.resolver' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'Resolver<AuthenticationData, any> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Resolver<FieldValues, any> | undefined'.
      Type 'Resolver<AuthenticationData, any>' is not assignable to type 'Resolver<FieldValues, any>
```

The implementation looks like this...

```js
<ControlledTextField
  name="email"
  label="Email"
  control={control}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem too. The solution I've come to was to pass the `Control` prop with a generic that extends the `FieldValues` type to the `ControlledTextField` component. From then on, you should be able to get various variables with the correct inferred types.

The component implementation should look something like this:

```
import { FormControl, Input } from "native-base"
import { Controller, UseControllerProps, Control, FieldPath, FieldValues } from "react-hook-form"

interface ControlledTextFieldProps<T extends FieldValues> extends UseControllerProps {
  label: string;
  control: Control<T>;
  name: FieldPath<T>;
  defaultValue: T[keyof T];
}

const ControlledTextField = ({ control, name, label, defaultValue, ...props }: ControlledTextFieldProps) => {
  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={name}
      render={({
        fieldState: { invalid, error },
        field: { onChange, onBlur, value },
      }) => (
        <FormControl mb="5" isInvalid={invalid}>
          <FormControl.Label>{label}</FormControl.Label>
          <Input
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onChange={onChange}
            value={value}
          />
          <FormControl.ErrorMessage>
            {error?.message ?? ""}
          </FormControl.ErrorMessage>
        </FormControl>
      )}
    />
  )
}

export default ControlledTextField
```

And then, when you are implementing the component:

```
<ControlledTextField
  name="email"
  label="Email"
  control={control}
  defaultValue=""
/>
```

Comment: I don't see you passing in the generic from the ControlledTextField into the ControlledTextFieldProps which is throwing errors for me. When I convert this to a function (easier for me) and get the generic T to pass into the ControlledTextFieldProps I get `Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'FieldValues'` which I remember I kept running into for some reason and don't know how to solve